# Automatically arrange references in increasing number

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have `\cite{b,c,a,d}` which generates `[2, 3, 1, 4]`.

Is it possible to automatically make them in increasing order without manually changing `\cite{b,c,a,d}`  to `\cite{a,b,c,d}`.

Any help and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If not using `natbib`, then add to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[sort,nocompress]{cite}
```

the `nocompress` option will prevent the default compression of consecutive numbers into ranges. If using `natbib`, load it using the `sort` option:

```
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will make [1]-[4]. But, I would like to see all [1,2,3,4]. Is this possible?

Comment: I found the answer, \usepackage[sort,nocompress]{cite}. Thanks for the pointer and help.

Comment: @Bill I've added the `nocompress` option to the answer; I forgot `cite` activates compression automatically.