# Automatically arrange citations in increasing number using biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

I have similar problem to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56182/automatically-arrange-references-in-increasing-number)

The question is essentially the same, but I use `biblatex`.

I have `\autocite{b,c,a,d}` which generates `[2, 3, 1, 4]`.

Is it possible to automatically make them in increasing order without manually changing `\autocite{b,c,a,d}` to `\autocite{a,b,c,d}`?

My code right now is:

```
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    maxbibnames=9,
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,%authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
```

Any help and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, it was exactly, what I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `sortcites` package option; a little example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{testbibxxyy.bib}
@Article{aksin,
  author       = {Aks{\i}n, {\"O}zge and T{\"u}rkmen, Hayati and Artok, Levent
                  and {\k{C}}etinkaya, Bekir and Ni, Chaoying and
                  B{\"u}y{\"u}kg{\"u}ng{\"o}r, Orhan and {\"O}zkal, Erhan},
  title        = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of
                  saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck
                  reactions},
  journaltitle = jomch,
  date         = 2006,
  volume       = 691,
  number       = 13,
  pages        = {3027-3036},
  indextitle   = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics},
}

@Article{angenendt,
  author       = {Angenendt, Arnold},
  title        = {In Honore Salvatoris~-- Vom Sinn und Unsinn der
                  Patrozinienkunde},
  journaltitle = {Revue d'Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique},
  date         = 2002,
  volume       = 97,
  pages        = {431--456, 791--823},
  hyphenation  = {german},
  indextitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
  shorttitle   = {In Honore Salvatoris},
  annotation   = {A German article in a French journal. Apart from that, a
                  typical \texttt{article} entry. Note the \texttt{indextitle}
                  field},
}

@Article{baez/article,
  author       = {Baez, John C. and Lauda, Aaron D.},
  title        = {Higher-Dimensional Algebra V: 2-Groups},
  journaltitle = {Theory and Applications of Categories},
  date         = 2004,
  volume       = 12,
  pages        = {423-491},
  version      = 3,
  eprint       = {math/0307200v3},
  eprinttype   = {arxiv},
  hyphenation  = {american},
  annotation   = {An \texttt{article} with \texttt{eprint} and
                  \texttt{eprinttype} fields. Note that the arXiv reference is
                  transformed into a clickable link if \texttt{hyperref} support
                  has been enabled.  Compare \texttt{baez\slash online}, which
                  is the same item given as an \texttt{online} entry},
}

@Article{bertram,
  author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
  title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on Riemann surfaces},
  journaltitle = jams,
  date         = 1996,
  volume       = 9,
  number       = 2,
  pages        = {529-571},
  hyphenation  = {american},
  shorttitle   = {Gromov invariants},
  annotation   = {An \texttt{article} entry with a \texttt{volume} and a
                  \texttt{number} field},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    maxbibnames=9,
    backend=biber,
    style=numeric,%authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false,
   sortcites
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testbibxxyy.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{bertram,baez/article,aksin,angenendt}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're also interested in compressing ranges switch from `style=numeric` to `style=numeric-comp`.