# Numerical order of citation - bibliography in Lyx

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I'm writing my PhD thesis in Lyx.
I'm using a master lyx document to compile the various chapters in their own child lyx file.
Each child has its own bibtex bibliography at the end.
Articles should appear in order of citation in the text: "Hello [1], this [2] is [3] a text [4-7]."
"Bibliography
[1] Ref 1
[2] Ref 2
[3] Ref 3
..."
I'm struggling to obtain each bibliography done.  Here are the problems:

1. Citations in the text are chaotic like this: "Hello [42], this
   [31] is [27]."
2. They should also be compact when subsequent
   citations are called "[4-7]"
3. Bibliography at the end has entries
   chaotically distributed, no matter the style I use (seems).
4. Citation of other chapters are present in each bibliography, despite
   different .bib have created for each  chapter.

Settings: both master and child docs with Sectioned Bibliography selected. For each bibliography I  tried unsert, plain,... (others return errors). 
Citation style: default (numeric), Processor. (Default). Document class: sectcnreset,sort&compress.

Comment: How are you doing multiple bibliographies?  This is not supported without an additional package (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98660/106162).  Are you loading natbib?  That should sort and compact `\cite{ref5,ref1,ref2,ref3}` type commands with the `sort&compress` option (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56186/106162), while `unsrtnat` (the natbib `unsrt`) will sort references by order of appearance.