# How to arrange reference numbering using plainnat style

Tags: biblatex, citing, texmaker

I am using Texmaker as the editor for Latex. I want to sort the order of references in the text. It shows random order of the references using \cite{} like [52,2,36,11,49]. Here is the packages I am using.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}{}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathptm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsbsy,bm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\newcommand{\etal}{\emph{et al.}}
\newcommand{\fld}{\textrm{\footnotesize{f}}}
\newcommand{\ptcl}{\textrm{\footnotesize{p}}}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,footnotesep=1cm]{geometry}
```

I am using bibliography style plainnat. I appreciate any help.

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

Comment: Use the natbib package options `sort` or `sort&compress` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56182/106162)

Comment: I am using bib style plainnat, and I have already checked those posts however they didn't help!

Comment: Hang on, is it that you want to sort references in order of appearance (`\cite{ref1} \cite{ref2}` should be `[N] [N+1]`), or you want to sort a block of citations (`\cite{ref1} \cite{ref3,ref1,ref2}` should end up `[1] [1,2,3]`)?

Comment: I want my references to be sorted when they are mentioned in the text. So basically what I need is instead of having [31,2,54,18,23] to be [2,18,23,31,54].

Comment: That example is ambiguous, if you want `\cite{ref1} \cite{ref2}` to necessarily give `[1] [2]` (order of bibliography by order of citation) then you want the `unsrtnat` bibliography style.  If after `\cite{ref1} \cite{ref2}` has given `[1] [2]` you want `\cite{ref2,ref1}` to give `[1,2]` rather than `[2,1]` (order of citation block in ascending order) you want the `sort` or `sort&compress` package option of natbib.